# How to properly use sendmail with php with mutliple domain

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sendmail

I'm hosting two websites created with wordpress on a server.
Those website should be able to send mails to users, but it fails for almost receivers (except maybe gmail).
I found that the problem was that the mails was sent by the user `www-data@myserver` and were rejected.

I would like to configure my `php.ini` to use `/usr/sbin/sendmail -f` to provide a `from` value so that the emails would have a valid domain.

My problem is how to be able to specify multiple domains here so that each website would send mail with an address like `noreply@mydomain.com` with `mydomain` matching to each website's one.

I saw I could use php's `mail()` and provide an argument with `-f` but it is deprecated before wordpress `wp_mail()`'s function.

How can I achieve what I want ?

Comment: When you say you have two websites, I guess they are VirtualHosts under Apache? You can use the `PHPINIDir` directive under the VirtualHost configuration to specify that different sites use their own individual php.ini files. This may allow you to do what you want, although I'm sure there are other neater ways around this issue also.

Comment: Yes, I have two distinct virtual hosts. Thank you I didn't know about PHPINDir, this might be solution, at least till I will find something better.

Comment: Acutally reading a little further `PHPINIDir` may not work properly in VirtualHost context. Look at `php_value` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Just create email accounts for each WordPress and set it up to use SMTP to send emails using real email accounts.

WordPress does support this natively.